# cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public List<History> getHistory(List<Long> Ids) {
    String queryString = "FROM History where txyId in (:Ids) ORDER BY closeTime DESC";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getObject().getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameterList("Ids", Ids).setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(1);
    return query.list();
    
}
```

Erroe:

2020-08-14 00:03:18,952 [http-nio-8080-exec-3:] c.t.c.u.e.GlobalExceptionHandler.handleException:243
ERROR - new Global exception handled!    Message = java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger

Comment: Could you please show the `History` entity. What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: I am using 5.3.x

Comment: What type does the field `txyId` have?

Comment: private BigInteger txyId;